# SAML SSO SFDS as IdP

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

Our requirement is to call an external web API with Salesforce generated SAML assertion then the API will return an authentication token for invoking subsequent other web services to retrieve data and display on VF page. I've implemented some APEX classes for invoking these other services. But now the authentication part really got me stuck.

I assume in our scenario SFDC is acting as Identity Provider? and we will put SFDC user id as SAML attribute?

I have spent a lot of time trying to locate documents on how to achieve this but with no luck.

I am not sure how I can get the SAML response generated from SFDC? I've enable our org as Identity Provider, but I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: any way you find out todo sso using rest apis? especially how to get saml response from salesforce? Is it even possible with APIs?